# How to track estimation with remaining work in Scrum process?

Tags: process, scrum

I have been practicing Scrum and user stories estimation for few weeks and now I'm trying to track our estimation to know how good it was. So I created a table like this one:

[image]

note: overestimation = original - completed

That didn't help me much because we're still not accurate in estimation and each sprint we get some remaining work. Thus the overestimation column isn't accurate in explaining how good our estimation was. Anyone got a better method to track estimation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on Software Engineering SE or Project Management SE instead.

Answer (score 4):

From your post, I have to assume that you're estimating your user stories in hours rather than story points? (Otherwise, I cannot see how you would perform a check on your estimation).

In my experience, this approach is flawed. Relative estimation has proven to be a better technique for estimating user stories and [according to Jeff Sutherland](http://scrum.jeffsutherland.com/2010/04/story-points-why-are-they-better-than.html), one of the co-creators of Scrum, far more accurate too.

Estimating in hours more usually occurs at the task level. You could perform analysis here but I'd question why you'd want to do it. What value would you derive from it?

If your aim is to help developers become better at estimating, the sprint retrospective is the right place to do this. Estimates made will be fresh in developer's minds and the reason for under / over estimation could be inspected and any adaptations considered (but, let the developers decide if this is an area they want to improve on - don't force it on them)

To summarize:

- Consider using relative estimation with items like story points at the user story level
- Let the developers decide if they need to improve their estimation at the sprint retrospective
- If you still feel you need to perform an analysis of estimation accuracy, ask what
  value you will derive from it and discuss it with the scrum team

Answer (score 1):

Please conduct sprint retrospective meetings on time, without fail. That is great opportunity INSPECT and ADOPT. There you can discuss about what went wrong, in your case its estimates, and put this as point for improvement for next sprint.

I will also suggest to conduct Backlog grooming meetings on timely manner. And lets say if you are following three weeks sprint then reduce it to two weeks. I will suggest to  make your sprint backlog item's ( or sub item's) of two days. That will help to make your estimation more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend tracking completed work or mis-estimations in a Scrum context. Estimates in hours/days are there primarily as a pretext for discussion and exploration of tasks during the Sprint Planning meeting, and secondarily to track the sprint progress day after day. To that end, tracking remaining work is enough.

If the team under or over estimates, **1/** there's not much you can trustily improve about it, **2/** it doesn't affect the amount of value produced by the team in the end anyway and **3/** it has no consequences outside of the sprint.

The team will naturally adjust their commitment in subsequent sprints based on *velocity*, not time estimates.

Better to focus on improving the work itself than improving your predictions about the work, if you want my opinion.